# Ruby app pushed to Heroku displaying issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am running a Ruby on Rails application with a PostgreSQL database. This is the first time I pushed an app with its database to heroku, so I had no idea what to expect. What I got was my main page working as intended; but the Users page (page created by Rails `scaffold` command wich should display database query functions ex. "Create User") is not showing. Instead, a "We're sorry, but something went wrong. We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly." This hasn't change since yesterday.

Also, my app main heroku page is displaying some "Dyno" bars. These seem like progress bars, only they add payment required if I try to pull them foward. On top of each bar, a command is listed:

- **web** bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
- **worker** bundle exec rake jobs:work

I have modified my **database.yml** file so it matches the Postgres database in Heroku specifications, so it goes something like this now:

```
>     production:
>       adapter: postgresql
>       encoding: unicode
>       database: d6i4fnhdh54239
>       pool: 5
>       username: evlptakrsjivpi
>       password: N6upI3-WSvca90zMXp8iKOXxh2
>       host: ec2-23-21-243-117.compute-1.amazonaws.com
>       port: 5432
```

But this file is in the **.gitignore** by default, so commiting the changes doens't even count as a commit. I'm really lost here. This is my heroku log error:

```
> 2013-12-11T21:17:28.683243+00:00 app[web.1]:
> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation
> "users" does not exist 2013-12-11T21:17:28.683243+00:00 app[web.1]:
> LINE 1: SELECT     "users".* FROM       "users"
> 2013-12-11T21:17:28.683243+00:00 app[web.1]:                          
> ^ 2013-12-11T21:17:28.683243+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT     "users".*
> FROM       "users"): 2013-12-11T21:17:28.683243+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> app/controllers/users_controller.rb:5:in `index'
> 2013-12-11T21:17:28.683243+00:00 app[web.1]:
> 2013-12-11T21:17:28.683243+00:00 app[web.1]:
> 
>  !    Command cancelled.
```

Comment: run heroku logs -n 1500 to see what is the issue or heroku logs --tail for live logs

Comment: '2013-12-11T21:17:28.683243+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2013-12-11T21:17:28.683243+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT     "users".* FROM       "users"
2013-12-11T21:17:28.683243+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2013-12-11T21:17:28.683243+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT     "users".* FROM       "users"):
2013-12-11T21:17:28.683243+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:5:in `index'
'

Comment: what does the UndefinedTable error means?

Comment: It's telling you the table doesn't exist.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku will recreate your database.yml to match their internal database schemes, so you don't need to do that manually.  However, you do need to treat it like a distinct database, which means separate database migrations.

So, make sure you run `heroku run rake db:migrate` to update your tables.

Comment: It worked :) thank you and sorry for the newbie stuff

Comment: Anytime, that's why this site exists.  :)